# PHP: Xdebug access denied exit with code 0

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have set the PHP project on Mac with XAMPP and installed Xdebug there, but on my PhpStorm I get:

[image: PhpStorm terminal image]

I did not manage to find anything on the web.

My php.ini

```ini
[xdebug]
;zend_extension=xdebug.so
zend_extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9002
xdebug.remote_log="/mnt/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=phpstorm
xdebug.remote_mode = req
```

Comment: To me it looks like you are making some API (HTTP) request in that PHP code. The "Access denied" is the HTTP response of such request...

Comment: I tried few pages, and few configuration inputs but it's always the same and my phpinfo() show everything is set up well. @LazyOne

Comment: Sorry. I cannot give a better advice from such limited info (I even have no idea hat command is run etc). But I clearly see the HTTP response on your screenshot. How you print it there (or what code/part of your app does it) -- I do not know since you better know what framework/libraries you are using and what they do.

Comment: BTW -- what Xdebug version do you have -- v2 or v3?

Answer (score 0):

I might be coming late to the party, but make sure XDebug has Write access to the folder, let alone if you're using Docker.

If it's local, then just out of investigation try:

```
chmod 777 /mnt/log/xdebug.log
```

However, I'd rather choose to state a folder for the logging over a file.

If it's running within Docker, then "chmod" the actual mounted folder instead.